# no script tag is not working as wished

Tags: javascript, html

```
$private void writeFormularHead(String path, FormControls formcontrols) {
   this.Sourcecode.AppendLine("\t<head>");
   InsertHeadLines();
   this.Sourcecode.AppendLine("\t\t <script type='text/javascript'>");
   writeJavaScript(formcontrols);
   this.Sourcecode.AppendLine("\t\t</script>");
   this.Sourcecode.AppendLine("\t\t <noscript>" + NoscriptMessage + " </noscript>");
   this.Sourcecode.AppendLine("\t</head>");
}
```

When I enabled  JavaScript in my browser, a form is loaded which I have included inside my `script` tag - but when I disabled my JavaScript a message inside a `noscript` tag is displayed which is ok but also a form is loaded which I have included inside my `script` tag. I just want to display a message which I have written inside a `noscript` tag when JavaScript is disabled. But it is not working.

Comment: Post your generated HTML, not this backend generator. It looks OK, though we can't see what's inside `formcontrols`. Should work. Try again, perhaps? : )

Comment: inside formcontrold i have written all functions to create a web form ist working fine .will try again